# Run different Gitlab pipeline jobs depending on the tag

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I would like to achieve this Gitlab CI/CD behaviour:

Two jobs defined in the pipeline:

- `job_beta` triggered when a tag is created with a semver number containing a "-rc*" suffix. For example: `v1.0.0-rc1`.
- `job_production` triggered when a tag is created with a semver number, without any suffix. For example: `v1.0.0`.

Is there a way to parse the `$CI_COMMIT_TAG` variable in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file of the project? Or any other ideas about how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this kind of behaviour, you can rely on the [only](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#only--except) keyword to control which job will be created. Simply specify a regular expression that will either match a semver with the `rc` suffix or one without any suffix.

You could do it the following way if your semantic versions are prefixed with `v`:

```
build-beta:
  image: your-build-image:latest
  stage: build
  only:
    - /^v[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+-rc[0-9]+$/
  script:
    - ./build-beta.sh # Do something...

build-prod:
  image: your-build-image:latest
  stage: build
  only:
    - /^v[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/
  script:
    - ./build-prod.sh # Do something...
```

You can also achieve something similar with the [rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules) keyword by matching [`$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) with the appropriate regex in an `if` condition.